# Getting list of browser cookies with ruby

Tags: ruby, cookies, tcpserver

I'm trying to code a tiny ruby server using TCPServer but can't get the hang of getting the list of cookies from the browser's response. Below is the code for the server - it will serve the same html for all connections except js.

```
require 'socket'
server = TCPServer.new('localhost', 2000)

class Serveit
  def initialize(socket, content)
    @socket = socket
    @content = content
  end

  def content
    # @content
    @content = File.read('./partials/header.html.erb')
  end

  def socket
    @socket
  end

  def url
    @url = @socket.gets.split(' ')[1]
  end

  def request
    @socket.gets
  end
end

loop do
  s = Serveit.new(server.accept, rand(1..100000000).to_s)

  if s.url == "/js"
    content = File.read('app.js').to_s
    s.socket.print "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" + "Content-Type: application/javascript\r\n" + "Content-Length: #{content.bytesize}\r\n" + "Connection: close\r\n"
    s.socket.print "\r\n"
    s.socket.print content
    s.socket.close
  else
    s.socket.print "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" + "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" + "Content-Length: #{s.content.bytesize}\r\n" + "Connection: close\r\n"
    s.socket.print "\r\n"
    s.socket.print s.content
    s.socket.close
  end
end
```

The .js file contents is a simple document.cookie to set a cookie. I've tried getting the list using CGI but all i can manage is a a prompt on the terminal to manualy insert cookies.

My understanding is that you're supposed to capture the browser response headers that will include the cookies but i can't quite figure out how to do that.

Comment: See also the built-in [webrick library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html), an easier way to make a tiny HTTP server.  But if your goal is to learn how HTTP servers work, then carry on.

Comment: could you require another library like [this library](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) to use that could do most of it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the cookies you need to `gets` all the headers from the socket:

```
headers = []
while (line = @socket.gets) != "\r\n"
  headers << line
end
```

This will `gets` a line of text until you hit a blank line.

With that, the `headers` variable will contain all the unparsed headers from the request. You can find the browser cookies in a header prefixed with `Cookie:`.

I finished a toy project once where I implemented a web server in pure ruby, you can check out my [http parser here](https://github.com/DiegoSalazar/kwipper_challenge/blob/master/lib/kwipper/http_parser.rb).